# Get ALSA peak value from C code

Tags: c, linux, api, audio, alsa

I'm trying to retrieve the current audio peak value using ALSA and C. I would prefer to have this value as a scalar between 0.0 and 1.0 (or perhaps 0 and 100). On Windows I use [IAudioMeterInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd368230%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which allows me to construct a very basic VU meter.

EDIT: I am referring to detecting speaker output only, not microphone.

Comment: It's not clear at all which signal you want to get the instantanous volume of; the input (microphone) or the output (what's playing)? Both? I would guess the latter, but @TheCodeArtist seems to guess the former. Basically, the question is confusing.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. I have updated my question, I am referring to detecting speaker/playback output only. Like a standard peak/db meter would.

Comment: @unwind Yes, I was under the wrong impression. There doesn't seem to a straightforward way to do what the op requires though. [**This answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18614291/319204) is a desperate workaround that i could think of...

Answer (score 1):

ALSA does not have a current audio peak value.

Loop over the samples to get the maximum value when you're writing or reading them.

Comment: This allows a a program to analyse ONLY the audio being played by itself. The audio that is actually being played on the system's playback device would include streams being played simultaneously by other programs as well.

Answer (score 1):

Using `snd_pcm_readi` appears to work, See the example below:

```
static float GetLevel (void)
{
    float result = 0.0f;
    snd_pcm_t* waveform;

    // Open and initialize a waveform
    if (snd_pcm_open (&waveform, "default",
        SND_PCM_STREAM_CAPTURE, 0) != 0)
        return 0;

    // Set the hardware parameters
    if (!snd_pcm_set_params (waveform, SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE,
        SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED, 2, 48000, 1, 0))
    {
        // Read current samples
        short buffer[256];
        if (snd_pcm_readi (waveform, buffer, 128) == 128)
        {
            // Compute the maximum peak value
            for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
            {
                // Substitute better algorithm here if needed
                float s = buffer[i] / 32768.0f;
                if (s < 0) s *= -1;
                if (result < s) result = s;
            }
        }
    }

    snd_pcm_close (waveform);
    return result;
}
```

I remain skeptical, however, that this is a good solution.